# Chrome isn't loading my js file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My page is very basic

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <canvas id="can"></canvas>
    <video autoplay id="vid" style="cursor:pointer"></video><br>
    <script type="application/javascript;version=1.7" src="8bit.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It loads the JavaScript Firefox, but does not in Chrome.

If I copy and paste the contents of the JavaScript file into the console in Chrome, then it runs fine.

Why doesn't it load from the script tag in Chrome?

Comment: I read "Chrome isn't loading my life". Chrome is such a sick dude sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essence from the MDN about [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility) keyword:

> The keyword `let` is supported in Chrome only for testing purposes only in the Console and not in the normal flow. Chrome doesn't support `let` but Firefox does.

Replace the following:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7" src="8bit.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="8bit.js"></script>
```

Chrome makes a strict decision on `type` attribute. So please use that carefully. Only for Firefox, this is valid:

> Only available to code blocks in HTML wrapped in a `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` block (or higher version). Beware, however, that as this is a non-standard feature, this will most likely break support for other browsers. XUL script tags have access to these features without needing this special block.

**Workaround for Chrome:**

To enable these special keywords, add the following code on the top of the script block:

```
"use strict";
```

Comment: This causes problems because I'm using the `let` keyword in for loops.

Comment: @MattEllen What happens when you use my solution?

Comment: It stops working in bot firefox and chrome. `SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier` is the error in firefox. there is no error in chrome.

Comment: @MattEllen Yes, those extensions are not ECMA-Standard, they are supported only by the Mozilla implementation.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will post a new question about `let`

Comment: @MattEllen I have added a workaround.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87165/discussion-between-matt-ellen-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

You use the doctype for HTML5, and the script default is javascript, so this will also work:

```
<script src="8bit.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer is technically correct for the question. The type attribute is no longer needed as it will default to `text/javascript`. OP did not say in his question that he was testing experimental ES6 functionality. So, +1 !

Comment: Thanks - btw you've saved my dignity :)

Comment: It was the same thing I said. But the issue is different. I removed my downvote.